# how to collect value from dynamic input and steps in ASP.NET Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, controls, wizard

I'm trying to create a dynamic survey form based on dynamic data by using [ASP.NET `Wizard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.aspx).

I can create dynamic steps and dynamic inputs without any problem. However, the last step, when I submit the form, I won't be able to collect all information from each steps.

Any idea?

```
Wizard wizard1 = new Wizard();
wizard1.Style.Add("width", "100%");

//wizard1.DisplaySideBar = false;
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{   
    WizardStep step1 = new WizardStep();
    step1.ID = "step" + i.ToString();
    step1.Title = "step" + i.ToString();

    PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();
    ph.ID = "ph" + i.ToString();
    ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h1>Step." + i.ToString() + "</h1>"));

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "step" + i.ToString() + "tb";            
    ph.Controls.Add(tb);
    step1.Controls.Add(ph);
    wizard1.WizardSteps.Add(step1);
}

wizard1.FinishButtonClick += atWizardCompleted;
wizard_container.Controls.Add(wizard1);
```

Comment: I've never heard anything about the ASP.NET Wizard. I found a really old tutorial in PDF files I am using to help build a survey. If you figure this out, you should definitely post more about it! I'm stuck on skip logic and saving the answers to my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I found the solution by using Control.Find().